# Проблема с отправкой данных с помощью ajax в приложение на asp .net core

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

Доброго времени суток. Проблема в том что в приложение не передаются данные из скрипта на js, вот код скрипта:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Home/MessageHandler',
    data: "Test msg",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == true) {
            alert("Сообщение доставлено");
            location.reload();
        }
        else {
            alert("Внимание! Сообщение не доставлено!");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Произошел сбой");
    }
});
```

При запуске он переходит в ветку alert("Внимание! Сообщение не доставлено!");

Вот код контроллера который должен обработать сообщение:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MessageHandler(string data)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"\n\nMessageHandler data: {data}\n\n");
    string result = "Сообщение " + data;
    return Json(result);
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Чтобы понять, почему у тебя не работает AJAX нужно скинуть скриншот запроса в панели инструментов разработчика, так будет гораздо проще понять в чем проблема.

Comment: Почему `data` вообще должна быть true? В текущей реализации `data` будет равна "Сообщение "

Comment: Да вы правы проверка строки на истину это бред, сказалось то что это копипаст код. решил проблему переписью контроллера:        public Object MessageHandler()
        {

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
            string data = sr.ReadToEnd();

            string result = "Сообщение " + data;
            return result;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Решил пробелму переписав контроллер так:

```
   public Object MessageHandler()
    {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
        string data = sr.ReadToEnd();

        string result = "Сообщение " + data;
        return result;
    }
```

Скрипт:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Home/MessageHandler',
    data: "Test msg данные тут",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Произошел сбой");
    }
});
```

Все работает но я не уверен что все сделал верно.

Answer (score -1):

Для отладки лучше пользоваться консолью (console.log() например).
Через алерт объекты не просмотришь, только строчные или приводящиеся к строчному виду данные (у объекта редко кто .toString() расписывает). А вот через консоль можно прогнать почти любой объект.

Касательно твоего вопроса. Проверяем в консольке:

```
-> "string response" == true
<- false
```

Ну что тут поделать, строка не равна